# Prove that $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ is a metric space

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of the natural numbers

> Prove that $d_1(x,y)=| x-y|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{N}$.

**My attempt:**

1. $|x-y| \geqslant 0$ and $|x-y| = 0 \iff x=y$ ✓
2. $|x-y| = |y-x|$ ✓
3. $|x-z| \leqslant |x-y|+|y-z|$ from triangle inequality ✓

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: No. Because the name is Cauchy-Schwarz. :) Seriously though, why do you use Cauchy-Schwarz at all?

Comment: And you attempt to prove that $d_1$ is a *metric* on $\mathbb N$, so that $\langle\mathbb N,d_1\rangle$ is a *metric space*.

Comment: , In $1$ and $2$ I think that there is nothing to prove, how can I prove $3.$?

Comment: Can you prove that $|u+v|\leq|u|+|v|$? If so then you are ready. Just substitute $u=x-y$ and $v=y-z$.

Comment: I will try that @drhab

Comment: Btw, if you are working on $\mathbb N$ then you can use $|u|=u$ for every $u\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Your comment was needed @drhab

Comment: Warning:  the equation $|u+v|\leq|u|+|v|$ can only be used if it is proved for $u,v\in\mathbb Z$. This because eventually negative $u=x-y$ and $v=y-z$ are substituted. So my former comment is a bit misleading.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry it is triangle inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) $|x-z| = |x -y +y -z| \le  |x-y|+|y-z|$

Comment: Very nice$~~~~~$

Answer (score 1):

You need some elaboration, not just tick marks. For example, you can't just say $|x-y|=0\iff x=y$. You have to **explain** why that's true. Why couln't I have some $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$, but $|x-y|=0$?

Same with the second property. **Why** is $|x-y|$ equal to $|y-x|$?

And again with the third. Saying

> $|x-z|\leq |x-y| + |y-z|$ from triangle inequality

Is not enough. The triangle inequality says that $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$, which is different from the inequality you want to prove. Some more elaboration is in order here.

Comment: Yes you are right, now I'm trying to prove that

Comment: @Error404 You also need to prove the first two properties.